# Determine whether a set generates a residue field of an invariant ring

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, symmetric-groups, symmetric-functions, determinantal-ideals

Fix two positive integers $m>n$.

Let $(A|Y)$ be an $m\times (n+1)$ augmented matrix consisted of $m\times (n+1)$ indeterminates, where $Y$ is a column symbolic vector of length $m$.

Denote $R=\mathbb{Z}[A,Y]$ the polynomial ring with $m\times (n+1)$ indeterminates over the integer ring, and $\mathfrak{p}:=J_{n+1}(A|Y)$ the (prime) determinant ideal generated by all $(n+1)$-minors of $(A|Y)$.

Consider the invariant subring $R^{\Sigma_m}=\mathbb{Z}[A][s_1(Y),\cdots,s_m(Y)]$ and the prime ideal $\mathfrak{q}=\mathfrak{p}\cap R^{\Sigma_m}$, where symmetric group $\Sigma_m$ acts on $R=\mathbb{Z}[A,Y]$ by only substituting $y_i$ and $s_i(Y)$ means the $i$-th elementary symmetric polynomial of $Y$.

Let $k(\mathfrak{q})$ be the residue field of $R^{\Sigma_m}$ at $\mathfrak{q}$. My question is:

Does $s_1(Y),\cdots,s_{n+1}(Y)$ generates $k(\mathfrak{q})$ over $\mathbb{Q}(A)$?

These are what I have known:

1. $k(\mathfrak{q})≃k(\mathfrak{p})$(arguing by decomposition group and CRT);
2. $(s_1(Y),⋯,s_n(Y))$ is a transcendental basis over $\mathbb{Q}(A)$(derived from regular sequence);
3. $[k(\mathfrak{q}):\mathbb{Q}(A)(s_1(Y),⋯,s_n(Y))]≤n!$(derived from Bezout's theorem);
4. When $m=n+1$, $\mathfrak{q}^e$ is a principal ideal generated by $f_{n+1,n}:=\prod_{\sigma\in\Sigma_{n+1}}{\sigma(\mathrm{det}(A|Y))}$, which is symmetric in $Y$. Hence $\mathfrak{q}$ is generated by $g_{n+1,n}(s_1,\cdots,s_{n+1})$, where $g_{n+1,n}(s_1(Y),\cdots,s_{n+1}(Y))=f_{n+1,n}(Y)$ and $\deg_{s_{n+1}}{g_{n+1,n}}=n!$.

I conjectured that $k(\mathfrak{q})=\mathbb{Q}(A)(s_1(Y),⋯,s_{n+1}(Y))$ and $[k(\mathfrak{q}):\mathbb{Q}(A)(s_1(Y),⋯,s_n(Y))]=n!$. To prove these, I have tried to find the minimal polynomial of $s_{n+1}$ over $\mathbb{Q}(A)(s_1(Y),⋯,s_{n}(Y))$ by induction. But the pattern is too complicated for me to induct. Besides, I have computed $g_{3,2}$ in Maple, which has thousands of terms and has some symmetry. The computation of Groebner basis is also failed.

I will be very appreciate if you can provide some references. Thanks again!